# How to loop groups of codes with different content in each group?

Tags: php

I'm writting a MyBB plugin. It's work now, but I have some issues while trying to loop sets of code.

For example. I'm using this code to get data from database.

```
//Some codes...
$lctg_rcposts .= '
    <div class="bt-lite">
    <div class="bt-link">Newest Posts</div>
    <div id="bt-holder">';

$count = $db->simple_select("threads", "COUNT(tid) AS threads", "$uview");
$threadcount = $db->fetch_field($count, "threads");
$sets = $threadcount / $totalsets;

for ($i=1; $i<=$sets; $i++)
{
    $lctg_rcposts .= '<div class="bt-set">';
    $query = $db->query("SELECT t.*
        FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."threads AS t
        $ufids AND t.visible = '1' GROUP BY t.tid
        ORDER BY t.lastpost DESC LIMIT 3"
    );

    while($data = $db->fetch_array($query))
    {
        $datacache['tid'] = $data;
    }

    if(!empty($datacache))
    {
        foreach($datacache as $data)
        {
            //Some code...
            $lctg_rcposts .= '
            <a href="thread-' . $data['tid'] . '-lastpost.html">
            ' . $subject .'
            </a>';
        }
    }

    $lctg_rcposts .= '</div>'; //--- End of Sets
}

$lctg_rcposts .= '</div></div>'; //--- End of File
```

The problem is the content of each set will be same (of course). But I want to this will has model like below. (a good set has only 3 links)

```
<div class="bt-set>
<a>1</a>
<a>2</a>
<a>3</a>
</div>
<div class="bt-set>
<a>4</a>
<a>5</a>
<a>6</a>
</div>
... and goes on ...
```

Please give me some suggestions. Thanks a lots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [array_chunk](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) for break your $datacache array into arrays if the size that you want.

```
if(!empty($datacache))
{
    foreach(array_chunk($datacache, 3, true) as $chunk)
    {
        //put <div> here
        foreach ($chunk as $data) {
            //Some code...
            $lctg_rcposts .= '
            <a href="thread-' . $data['tid'] . '-lastpost.html">
            ' . $subject .'
            </a>';
        }
        //put </div> here
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I love you so much, Nelson. It's work like a charm :D